# неконкретное копирование элементов при удалении копируемого массива в C++

Tags: c++

После java изучаю C++, потихоньку разбираюсь в удалении объектов и в указателях.
Пытаюсь написать свой ArrayList в cpp. При заполнении внутреннего массива , создается новый массива, туда складываются данные, а затем очищаю память и переношу указатель на новый массив.

```
#include "ArrayList.h"
#include <iostream>
ArrayList::ArrayList() {
    lenght=0;
    sizeArr=10;
    values= new char[sizeArr];//
}

bool ArrayList::checkIndex(int index){
    if(index<0 || index>lenght-1){
        throw index;
        return false;
    }
        return true;

}
char* ArrayList::copyarray(char *src,int len, int  newlenght){

 char* newArr=new char[newlenght];
 for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
     newArr[i]=src[i];
 }
delete [] src;
src=nullptr;
 src=newArr;
 return src;
}
char ArrayList::get(int index){
    checkIndex(index);
    return values[index];
}
void ArrayList::remove(int){

}


int ArrayList::indexOf(const char* val){
    return 0;
}
void ArrayList::add(const char* val){
    values[lenght]=val;
    lenght++;
    if(lenght==sizeArr){
        sizeArr=(sizeArr*2)-(sizeArr/2);

        copyarray(values,lenght,sizeArr);
    }

}






int ArrayList::size(){
    return lenght;
}


bool ArrayList::isEmpty(){

    return lenght==0;
}


bool ArrayList::conteins(const char* val){
    return indexOf(val)!=-1;
}
int ArrayList::hashCode(){
    return 1;
}






ArrayList::~ArrayList() {
    //delete values;
}
```

метод main:

```
    ArrayList  list;
list.add("hello");
list.add("hello1");
list.add("hello2");
list.add("hello3");
list.add("hello");
list.add("hello1");
list.add("hello2");
list.add("hello3");
list.add("hello");
list.add("hello1");
list.add("hello2");
list.add("hello3");
list.add("hello");
list.add("hello1");
list.add("hello2");
list.add("hello3");


for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
       cout<<list.get(i)<<endl
```

Если я не удаляю старый массив в методе copyarray, то выводится все нормально, а если удаляю, то выводится немного добавленных значений и какой то мусор.

Comment: Этот код не будет даже компилироваться, а вы рассказываете про какое-то "выводится"...

Comment: Ошибок очень много_ в каждом методе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `values= new char[sizeArr];`

Если `values` это `char *`, то `values[index]` уже `char`.

> `values[lenght]=val;`

И вы пытаетесь в `char` записать `const char *`.
К тому же нельзя `char *` присвоить `const char *`.
Вам нужно делать массив указателей `char **values;`, выделять память под новую строку и копировать её туда.
Пример:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

class ArrayList {
private:
    std::size_t array_size;
    std::size_t capacity;
    char **values;

    void array_realloc() {
        std::size_t new_capacity = std::size_t(capacity * 1.5);
        char **new_values = new char*[new_capacity];
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
            new_values[i] = values[i];
        }
        delete[] values;
        values = new_values;
        capacity = new_capacity;
    }

public:
    // инициализация. capacity должен быть объявлен в классе раньше values
    ArrayList() : array_size(0), capacity(10), values(new char*[capacity]) {}

    ~ArrayList() {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
            delete[] values[i];
        }
        delete[] values;
    }

    void add(const char* val) {
        if (array_size == capacity) {
            array_realloc();
        }
        std::size_t val_len = strlen(val) + 1; //+1 для '\0'
        values[array_size] = new char[val_len];
        std::strncpy(values[array_size], val, val_len);
        array_size++;
    }

    std::size_t size() const { return array_size; }

    char* get(std::size_t index) {
        if (index >= array_size) throw "Bad index";
        return values[index];
    }
};

int main() {
    ArrayList a;
    a.add("123");
    a.add("qwerty");
    a.add("zxcvb");
    a.add("asdf");
    a.add("lkhfgf");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << a.get(i) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Совсем не обьязателен массив указателей

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а что вы предлагаете?

Comment: можно просто взять участок памяти, достаточную для записи в нем в нем  ожидаемого результата и удалить старый

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> delete [] src;
> src=nullptr;
> src=newArr;
> return src;
> ```

Здесь вторая и третья строчка бесполезны, а то, что делает 4я нигде не используется.

Comment: А так я перекидываю свою указатель в третьей строчке на новый адрес в памяти, надеюсь:)

Comment: @Amos, зря надеешься.

Comment: А как   правильно будет?

Comment: @Amos, в данном случае так же, как в джаве.